# Express named placeholder routes on root

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

I'm currently building a MEAN app and I have routing setup as you'd expect (/login, /profile, /logout etc). I've come to the point now in my app where I'm building user profile pages and I'd like user profiles to be accessible from the root of the domain, like: `www.domain.com/:username`.

I currently have the following route which is defined at the end of my routes.js file and just before my catchall/wildcard routes.

```
app.get('/:username', function (req, res) {
    var username = req.params.username;
        usersTable.findOne({ 'local.username': username }, function (err, user) {               
            if (err)
                return err;

            if (!user)
                res.redirect('/');

            res.render('public-profile.ejs', {
                user: user
            });
        });
});

app.all('/*', function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.user) {
        res.sendfile('views/dashboard.html'); // for angular routing
    } else {
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
});
```

As it currently stands there is some interference between Express/Angular. If I visit /matthew which is a username and then try to load /profile from the URL bar, Angular doesn't catch this (/* route) and instead loads the default ('/') angular route.

My concern is that I wouldn't be able to create a /:username route in Angular because how will that page know what user data to show? Will I have to create an API call that reads the given URL which then looks for a user in the database with that name? (seems clunky?)

I'm pretty new to building large-scale webapps so advice on the architecture would be great.

Comment: if you want single page app with angular you wouldn't render the view from server you would mod_rewrite back to app entry point

Comment: @charlietfl that's what is happening in my /* route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in your post only configures the server-side routes, which has in fact nothing to do with Angular routing.

Angular is for single-page applications (SPA). If you want to use AngularJS on the client, you probably don't want to serve pages from the server, but return data, i.e your routes are meant for API calls only.

So, on the client-side, you should have something like :

```
myApp
.constant('MY_BACKEND_URL', 'http://www.domain.com')
.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) { // client-side route config

  $stateProvider
    .state('userProfile',{
    url: '/:username',
    templateUrl: 'views/user-profile.html',
    controller: 'UserProfileCtrl',
    resolve: { // lets you resolve asynchronously before page is loaded.
      userData: ['$http', 'MY_BACKEND_URL', '$stateParams', '$state', function ($http, MY_BACKEND_URL, $stateParams, $state) {
        return $http
          .get(MY_BACKEND_URL + '/' + $stateParams.username)// returns a promise of the user data fetch from the API.
          .catch(function (err) {
            $state.go('dashboard');
          });
      }]
    }
  });

  $stateProvider.state('dashboard',{
    url: '/',
    template: 'views/dashboard.html',
    controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
  });
}]);
```

And on the server side :

```
// config route for API call to user resource 
app.get('/user/:username', function (req, res) {
  var username = req.params.username;
  usersTable.findOne({ 'local.username': username }, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      res.json(500, err);
    } else if (!user) {
      res.json(404, {reason: "No such username", username: username});
    } else {
      res.json(200, user);
    }
  });
});
```

As a rule of thumb, routes on the client-side (Angular) configure pages, whereas routes on the server-side configure your API, i.e endpoints you call for fetching data.

By the way, you should remove the `return err;` statement from your callback, because there is no point in returning a value from a callback function that is meant for side-effects only. You probably want to replace it with something like :

```
if(err){
  res.json(500, err); // return internal server error response.
}
```

Comment: I see you've opted to use Angular UI for the Angular routing. Any benefits over Angulars UI vs Angular's built in $routeProvider in this case?

Comment: In this case, no significant benefits, but this seems to be the conventional way to do things with MEAN stacks, from what I saw at http://mean.io/#!/docs. Feel free not to use it if this seems to much to learn at one time.

Comment: I'm a little confused with the 'MY_BACKEND_URL' part of the function, if I replace this with the API endpoint (/users/:username) then the function isn't going to run because / is an illegal character in the parameters?

Comment: I've modified your answer with the correction function. Thanks for your help!

Comment: MY_BACKEND_URL is not about the endpoint, but the domain (I made a typo, it's corrected now).'MY_BACKEND_URL' is the name of an AngularJS service, which is a recommended way of configuring your backend url in one place only. I've modified the code to show you how.

Comment: Ah, makes total sense. I'm still learning angular so wasn't aware of .constant!